# DataflowBlock ITargetSource.AsObservable() not triggering OnNext()

Tags: c#, .net, tpl-dataflow

I'm trying to use a dataflowblock and I need to spy the items passing through for unit testing.

In order to do this, I'm using the `AsObservable()` method on `ISourceBlock<T>` of my `TransformBlock<Tinput, T>`,
so I can check after execution that each block of my pipeline have generated the expected values.

#### Pipeline

```cs
{
   ...
   var observer = new MyObserver<string>();
   _block  = new TransformManyBlock<string, string>(MyHandler, options);
   _block.LinkTo(_nextBlock);
   _block.AsObservable().Subscribe(observer);
   _block.Post("Test");
   ...
}
```

#### MyObserver

```cs
public class MyObserver<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    public List<Exception> Errors = new List<Exception>();
    public bool IsComplete = false;
    public List<T> Values = new List<T>();

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        IsComplete = true;
    }

    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        Values.Add(value);
    }

    public void OnError(Exception e)
    {
        Errors.Add(e);
    }
}
```

So basically I subscribe my observer to the transformblock, and I expect that each value passing through get registered in my observer "values" list.

But, while the `IsComplete` is set to true, and the `OnError()` successfully register exception,
the `OnNext()` method never get called unless it is the last block of the pipeline...
I can't figure out why, because the "nextblock" linked to this sourceBlock successfully receive the data, proving that some data are exiting the block.

From what I understand, the `AsObservable` is supposed to report every values exiting the block and not only the values that have not been consumed by other linked blocks...

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Related: [Using AsObservable to observe TPL Dataflow blocks without consuming messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579543/using-asobservable-to-observe-tpl-dataflow-blocks-without-consuming-messages) and also [How do I monitor progress in a TPL Dataflow mesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554941/how-do-i-monitor-progress-in-a-tpl-dataflow-mesh)

Answer (score 2):

Your messages are being *consumed* by `_nextBlock` before you get a chance to read them.

If you comment out this line `_block.LinkTo(_nextBlock);` it would likely work.

`AsObservable` sole purpose is just to allow a *block* to be *consumed* from *RX*. It doesn't change the internal working of the block to *broadcast* messages to multiple *targets*. You need a special block for that `BroadcastBlock`

I would suggest *broadcasting* to another *block* and using that to `Subscribe`

> BroadcastBlock’s mission in life is to enable all targets linked from
> the block to get a copy of every element published

```
var options = new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true};


var broadcastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<string>(x => x);
var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<string>();
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(s => Console.WriteLine("Action " + s));

broadcastBlock.LinkTo(bufferBlock, options);
broadcastBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, options);

bufferBlock.AsObservable().Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine("peek " + s));

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   await broadcastBlock.SendAsync(i.ToString());

broadcastBlock.Complete();
await actionBlock.Completion;
```

**Output**

```
peek 0
Action 0
Action 1
Action 2
Action 3
Action 4
peek 1
peek 2
peek 3
peek 4
```

Comment: Yes Indeed. but from documentation i was thinking that AsObservable was acting like a dynamic broadcast block and was offering a way to spy messages without consuming them... Is it an intended behavior ? It really disturbs me to modify my pipeline in order to spy what happens in a block.

Comment: @Duagt `AsObservable` purpose is just to allow a block to be consumed from **RX**. It doesn't change the internal working of the block to broadcast messages to multiple targets. You need a special block for that `BroadcastBlock`